# Microsoft Excel : Mid Function

Tags: excel

I want to use "MID Function" on cell below :

Malls > Palembang Icon > 05 Lantai 3

Hospitals > Public Hospital Siloam Karawaci > 3F

How to take only "Palembang Icon" & "Public Hospital Siloam Karawaci" by example above?

Comment: I removed the greetings per Stack Overflow convention. Would you mind putting a screenshot or something, your question is hard to comprehend right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use: FIND & MID. Your data at cell A1. Hope this help:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(">",A1,1)+1,FIND(">",A1,FIND(">",A1,1)+1)-FIND(">",A1,1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" > ",A1)+3,FIND(" > ",A1,FIND(" > ",A1)+3)-FIND(" > ",A1)-3)
```

or - if your locale required `;` as separators -

```
=MID(A1;FIND(" > ";A1)+3;FIND(" > ";A1;FIND(" > ";A1)+3)-FIND(" > ";A1)-3)
```

Comment: Why you didn't thank to me, too - my solution is also good? ;-)